# named server centos 7

Tags: debian, centos7

In the version of bind9 that runs on debian you had the option to declare forwarders in the named.conf.options file like so:

```
    forwarders {
        8.8.8.8;
        4.4.4.4;
            };
```

I am now running centos 7 and use the named bind server.  How can I declare this correctly in the /etc/named.conf file?

Comment: In the same way. CentOS 7 comes with BIND9 too. `named` is the name of the BIND9 executable. So what exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

The configuration structure itself is exactly the same (obviously a newer BIND version may have new features but this question is regarding some pretty basic functionality).

The only thing that I can think of that may be confusing is that Debian ships BIND with a default configuration file which uses [`include`](http://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.10/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.ch06.html#id2574748) directives to split the configuration into multiple files. (For example, they chose to put the [`options`](http://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.10/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.ch06.html#id2577539) section inside a file they named `named.conf.options`.)

As for [`forwarders`](http://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.10/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.ch06.html#id2584144), you can just put that inside [`options`](http://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.10/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.ch06.html#id2577539) in the normal `named.conf` configuration file, unless you want to mimic the same file layout by adding some `include` directives.

As a sidenote I'll just point out that forwarding by no means a requirement. BIND is perfectly capable of resolving names on its own, which may be preferable depending on your exact scenario.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I wanted to put in my own smart dns ip addresses instead of using the default dns supplied by my ISP.  Does this principle still work or no?

Comment: @chrisguk What I noted at the end is that you can let BIND do the recursive lookups instead of merely forwarding and relying on some other service to do the lookups for you. I'm not sure how your ISP's resolvers relate to this.